# How to add sphinx engine to mysql 5.7?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, storage-engine, sphinx

On my Ubuntu 18.04 machine using  `mysql 5.7` I have installed sphinxsearch 2.2 and now I'd like to add SphinxSE as an engine so that I can connect to it without language-specific medium.

The docs on [sphinix](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-2.3.2.html#sphinxse-installing) is rather old (for `MySQL 5.1.x`) and involves compiling mysql from source which I shy away from as it may break the existing stuff.

So I'm wondering if there is any straightforward solution for this which does not require source compilation?

Comment: Install MariaDB which will run on top of a MySQL-5.7 data directory. This has [SphinxSE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/about-sphinxse/) included in every [mariadb-server](https://mariadb.org/download/#mariadb-repositories) package on Ubuntu. Please check the [incompatibility documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/compatibility-differences/) and make a backup before upgrading.

Comment: I replaced MySQL with `Mariadb10.3` but sphinix does not appear in `show engines` until I fugred out that I should run `INSTALL SONAME 'ha_sphinx';`. Now it appeared in the engines. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @danblack please add `sphinx` to the tags. It is a beautiful piece of storage software and deserves a a tag, but I could not add that due to not having enough karma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install MariaDB which will run on top of a MySQL-5.7 data directory. This has [SphinxSE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/about-sphinxse/) included in every [mariadb-server](https://mariadb.org/download/#mariadb-repositories) package on Ubuntu.

You will need to [install the plugin](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/plugin-overview/#installing-a-plugin):

```
INSTALL SONAME 'ha_sphinx';
```

Please check the [incompatibility documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/compatibility-differences/) and make a backup before upgrading.

Note there is little effort being put into maintaining SphinxSE (note MariaDB is a few versions behind the latest 2.11, only minor differences looking at code), and that it has been dropped from [SphinxSE 3.0](https://github.com/sphinxsearch/sphinx/pull/32#issuecomment-508024646) onward.

I agree its a beautiful piece of software, and I know of one large production use of SphinxSE from a former client of mine who's websites are still running and appear to be using it still.